# Grouping the list and converting the response to JSON

Tags: django, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

a question.
there is a sample from the database

[image: sample]

uses Python2.7 + Django-1.67 + SqlAlchemy
How can you convert such a selection into a grouped list
so that the output is json, for example:
[Russia -> [Moscow -> [Lenina, Pushkina], Tomsk -> [Nekrasova]], ...]

There are about 600 records,
issued through api,
every time I load through request filters to the database, I think it is expensive,
can be as soon as possible with such a list to work to group?

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: What format is this selection returned as - `pandas.DataFrame`, `list of lists`, etc.?

Comment: <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>